# How to run code for a specific time listed

Tags: python, datetime

I have the below code which executes the main part when the current minute matches the minute specified under **minutetorun**

```
        thisminute = datetime.now().minute
        if (thisminute in minutetorun) and (thisminute != last_run):
            mainmodel(loaded_model, configdata)
            print("Windows service running.")
            logging.info("Windows service running.")
            last_run = thisminute
```

if **minutetorun = [5,35]** then **mainmodel(loaded_model, configdata)** will get executed every 5 and 35th minute.

I want to make a small change to this code. I want to change **minutetorun = [[0,35], [0,16], [1,35]...]** which means code will run when the time is 00:35, 00:16, 01:35 etc as specified. How can I do this? Also **(thisminute != last_run)** is added so that the code won't run twice for the same minute

Comment: Have you considered timedelta? https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import datetime
import time

minutetorun = [[0, 35], [0, 16], [1, 35]]
while True:
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    for time_to_run in minutetorun:
        if current_time.hour == time_to_run[0] and current_time.minute == time_to_run[1]:
            # do your things
    time.sleep(60)
```

The idea is to check current hour and minute every minute so that it won't run twice in a minute.